# Flume Appender Issue : Application threads are stuck when Flume Agents are down during heavy logging

Tags: java, performance, log4j2, flume, flume-ng

We are currently using below log4j jars

log4j-core-2.6.2, log4j-flume-ng-2.6.2

```
<Flume name="aggregatorApp" compress="false" type="Avro"
ignoreExceptions="true" batchSize="10" blocking="false" >
<Agent host="${flumeHostPrimary}" port="${flumePortPrimary}" />
<Agent host="${flumeHostSecondary}" port="${flumePortSecondary}" />
<FlumeEventFactory logType="APPLICATION"/>
<PatternLayout header="app" pattern="[%-5p] %d %c %X{correlationId} - %m" />

<AsyncLogger name="com.xyz.abc" level="debug"
additivity="false" blocking="false">
<AppenderRef ref="IDRESTSERVICELOG" />
<AppenderRef ref="aggregatorApp" level="INFO" />
<AppenderRef ref="CONSOLE" level="INFO"/>
</AsyncLogger>
```

1. When the flume agent is up and running application is running is smooth, And Log Events are successfully publishing to flume agents
2. If flume-Agents are down for some time, application threads are being stuck with below exceptions

```
Exception in thread "elasticsearch[_client_][generic][T#3]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
2019-02-01 07:43:23,618 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] WARN  org.apache.catalina.valves.StuckThreadDetectionValve- Thread "http-apr-8080-exec-7" (id=167) has been active for 20,392 milliseconds (since 2/1/19 7:42 AM) to serve the same request for htpps://xyz//directories/v1.0/search and may be stuck (configured threshold for this StuckThreadDetectionValve is 20 seconds). There is/are 1 thread(s) in total that are monitored by this Valve and may be stuck.
2019-02-01 07:46:18,619 [ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]] ERROR org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase- Unexpected death of background thread ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-42" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-50" Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" Exception in thread "I/O dispatcher 23" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]"
Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-38" Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-46" Exception in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-53" Exception in thread "I/O dispatcher 17" 
Exception: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError thrown from the UncaughtExceptionHandler in thread "http-apr-8080-exec-31"
```

Above exceptions are happening during heavy load (1MB logging per request) Note: we are doing load testing

As application is logging heavily but Flume appender not able to consume with same pace. We are suspecting Log4j ring buffer getting full which is blocking application threads and creating out of memory exceptions.

We have tried couple of actions considering there is something with Log4J appenders,

-Dlog4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy=Discard -Dlog4j2.enable.threadlocals=true -Dlog4j2.enable.direct.encoders=true

But above system properties are of no of use. are we missing something?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/1446916/remko-popma

Answer (score 0):

I would agree that the RingBuffer for the AsyncLogger is causing you to run out of memory. The default size of the ring buffer is 256K entries. What is the heap size for the JVM?

An alternate approach would be to use either the embedded or persistent variation of the FlumeAppender. These will cache the events in a local file channel before forwarding to the Flume agent. This will allow you to control how long the server can tolerate an outage by adjusting how much disk space is available. You will still be getting the advantage of the async logger but be protected from an outage.

Comment: What is the heap size for the JVM? -Its 1G to 2GB, I agree to your approach, We are not more concerned all realness of logs and our objective to make application not stuck with this logging